# Invalid resx file. Index and count must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, .net-core

Cannot build any .Net Core project With Resource.resx file using command `dotnet build`. It builds fine using Visual Studio, but gives an error using console.

> C:ConsoleApp1\Resource.resx : error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. Index and count must refer to a location within the string.\r [C:ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj]
>   C:ConsoleApp1\Resource.resx : error MSB3103: Parameter name: destinationIndex [C:ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj]

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1409

Comment: does that solved?